# Same applicationContext work with web application but not work with Spring test(spock),nested mybatis-config.xml can't be opened

Tags: mybatis, spock, applicationcontext, spring-test

I have configure file structure like this:

```
Project/
      war/
          WEB-INF/
                 applicationContext.xml
                 mybatis-config.xml
                 (both two xml files are under same directory:WEB-INF)
```

mybatis config in applicationContext.xml like this:

```
<!-- SqlSessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.domain.model" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml" />
    </bean>
```

Above configuration works in web application,and I have a spock unit test like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:war/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
public class SeniorPerWorkerMsgPusherTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    MyBatisMapper mapper
    .....
}
```

When run it,blow error got printed out:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in URL [file:war/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:407)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:381)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 131 more
```

Question is:
Why does same applicationContext work with web application but not work with Spring test(spock)?

Comment: What happens if you annotate your test class with `@WebAppConfiguration("war")`?

Answer (score 2):

Its hapends becouse Spring context for test should be in resources folder. You should move you mybatis config to resources or try to use a relative path to your context:

```
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml", "classpath*:mybatis-config.xml"})
```